# "Hello, World" on FreeBSD 11.2 using nasm

Tags: assembly, x86-64, freebsd

In assembly, I can't get the text to display. This asm code is directly out of a book (Low Level Programming by Igor Zhirkov). I cannot get the text to be displayed on my shell prompt but the program assembles fine then link with ld successfully.

```
global _start

section .data
message: db 'hello, world!', 10

section .text
_start:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1

  mov rsi, message
  mov rdx, 14
  syscall
```

[asm source code, "hello world"](https://pastebin.com/DKdknC54)

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct syscall number (i.e. have you cross-checked it against /usr/src/sys/kern/syscalls.master on your machine)?

Comment: You should be able to at least find the syscalls in /usr/include/sys/syscall.h . On Linux SYSCALL1(rax=1)is to write. On FreeBSD you'll find it to likely be 4 to WRITE and the EXIT syscall is 1

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to this example (tested on [FreeBSD 12](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/12.0/))

Save this into `hello.s`:

```
section .data

message:
    db      'hello, world!', 10

section .text

global _start
_start:
    mov     rax, 4
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, message
    mov     rdx, 14
    syscall

    mov     rax, 1
    xor     rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

Install `nasm`:

```
# pkg install nasm
```

Now assembleit with:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 hello.s
```

This will produce a file `hello.o` the one you will link using [ld](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ld(1)):

```
$ ld -m elf_amd64_fbsd -o hello -s hello.o
```

That should create a file named `hello`:

```
$ ./hello
hello, world!
```

If you just try:

```
$ ld -o hello -s hello.o
```

After trying to run it you may get this error:

```
ELF binary type "0" not known.
./hello: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
```

Check this [post (elf_i386_fbsd)](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/i386-assembly-example-does-not-work.55889/#post-317741) and also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494872/53084) for further reference.

To fix the code you paste, replace:

```
mov rax, 1
```

with

```
mov rax, 4
```

otherwise seems just to exit.

You can find these [syscall](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syscall&sektion=2) numbers in [`/usr/include/sys/syscall.h`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/syscall.h), for example:

```
/*
 * System call numbers.
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT-- this file is automatically generated.
 * $FreeBSD: stable/12/sys/sys/syscall.h 339002 2018-09-28 17:25:28Z jhb $
 */

#define SYS_syscall     0
#define SYS_exit        1
#define SYS_fork        2
#define SYS_read        3
#define SYS_write       4
#define SYS_open        5
#define SYS_close       6
#define SYS_wait4       7
                                /* 8 is old creat */
#define SYS_link        9
#define SYS_unlink      10
                                /* 11 is obsolete execv */
#define SYS_chdir       12
#define SYS_fchdir      13
#define SYS_freebsd11_mknod     14
#define SYS_chmod       15
#define SYS_chown       16
#define SYS_break       17
```